# SQL Server 2008 Find the min date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, min

I want the MIN(date) in the range for the each group calendarID/structureID and has a -1 value and grade 14. For instance calendarID 15555 and StructureiD 20391 would have the min(date) 5/28/2014.

**DAY TABLE**

```
date        instruction grade  calendarID  structureID
5/27/2014        0          14   15555        20391
5/28/2014       -1          14   15555        20391
5/29/2014       -1          14   15555        20391
5/30/2014        0          14   15555        20391
8/14/2013       -1          14   15516        19996
8/15/2013       -1          14   15516        19996
8/16/2013       -1          14   15516        19996
8/19/2013       -1          14   15516        19996
8/20/2013       -1          14   15516        19996
```

Comment: See the Microsoft TechNet article [Using Aggregate Functions in the Select List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213243(v=sql.80).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, was not sure how to search (terminology) to put in ....

Comment: No worries! And don't be discouraged by the downvotes – one of them was me – because it's not a reflection on you, but on the quality of your question *for other people*. I would strongly suggest that you read some of the top-voted questions in [sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?sort=votes&pageSize=30) or [sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server?sort=votes&pageSize=30) as that's a great way to pickup the terminology, which in turn makes further research *much* easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN([date]) 
FROM [DAY] 
WHERE instruction = '-1' 
  AND grade = '14' 
GROUP BY calendarID
       , structureID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result mapped for each row

```
select a.*,b.mindate
from DayTable a
inner join 
(select calendarID,structureID,min([date]) as mindate
from DayTable
where instruction=-1 and grade=14
group by calendarID,structureID) b
on a.calendarID=b.calendarID and a.structureID=b.structureID
```

or

```
with b as
(select calendarID,structureID,min([date]) as mindate
from DayTable
where instruction=-1 and grade=14
group by calendarID,structureID)
select a.*,b.mindate
from DayTable a
inner join b
on a.calendarID=b.calendarID and a.structureID=b.structureID
```